# How to setup ebean log level with log4j

Tags: java, log4j, ebean

I'm using `log4j` and `slf4j-log4j12` to print log in my project.

Problem is i don't want to show ebean's log.

I have read [Ebean logging config documentation](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/setup/logging) but it's for `logback`.

I have tried `log4j.logger.io.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction=INFO`. It's not work too.

Does anyone know how to config `log4j` for `ebean` to just printout `[INFO] level` or `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is my config for anyone who need it.

```
# Setup log level for Ebean
log4j.logger.io.ebean.SQL=INFO
log4j.logger.io.ebean.SUM=INFO
log4j.logger.io.ebean.TXN=INFO
log4j.logger.org.avaje.classpath.scanner=INFO
```